# How to resolve 404 error using CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, codeigniter

CSS and jquery does not applied in codeigniter. And it give

> error 404 not found

[image]

I have tried to load all the class of bootstrap. I used css property.

Comment: What is the location of your CSS files?

Comment: Assets folder should be outside of application folder.

Comment: It's not working . I try this before.and also now i try again

Comment: yes asset folder is outside the application folder

Comment: remove this index.php from your file url add htaccess to remove index.php set your base url and then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest building yourself a helper for including your assets so you don't need to keep referring back by direct path with each asset.

You are calling within the controller not outside of it, when I call this stuff I tend to use site_url() and call directly to the public assets folder from this, eg:

```
siteurl('assets/css/style.php')
```

This would find, for example: http://localhost/assets/css/style.php

an example of using this in a helper would be a function like:

```
    function assets($var)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper('url');

    return site_url('assets') . '/' . $var;
}
```

With this and the helper autoloaded, you could then just call assets('path/inside/assets/folder/')

Answer (score 0):

Use ../../../img/your_imgName in your CSS file